# Scala REST API call to a Java REST with FormParams

Tags: java, scala, rest, playframework

I wanted to know if you guys do know if it is possible in Scala to make a call to a Java REST client function which takes `@FormParam` params.

If my function in the Java client is this :

```scala
@Path("registerEmail")
@POST
public RegisterEmailResult doRegisterEmail(@FormParam("email") final String email, @FormParam("password") String password/* Some other params */) {
```

How can I pass some @FormParam params in Scala ? I tried this :

```scala
def registerEmail(registerEmail: RegisterEmail): Future[Boolean] =
post(
  url("/theUrl/registerEmail"),
  new Gson().toJson(registerEmail)
).map {
  case data => true
}.recover {
  case _ => false
}
```

The `RegisterEmail` model has all the field of the parameters of the Java function.

Did I miss something ? Otherwise I will have to do the Java function again with like `@QueryParams`, it seems to be maybe a better way.

Comment: Play! for the Scala API

Comment: You're trying to pass JSON, which isn't at all the same as form parameters. I don't recognize the framework you're using to post, but rather than the `new Gson().toJson(...)` thing, you need to build some kind of form object and add values to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simpler to understand your code if you include part of your imports as well. The url (which I assume is Play's play.api.libs.ws.WS.url(...)) can be utilised like this to pass form data:

```
WS.url("/theUrl/registerEmail")
  .post(Map("email" -> Seq("someone@somewhere.com"), 
            "password" -> Seq("secretish")))
```

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS for more details (specifically search for "Submitting form data")